# I got an error making a tile-based game. Could someone assist?

Tags: python, error-handling, pygame, atom-editor

I'm making a tile based game and following a tutorial ([Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zV2ewk-IGU)) and I was trying to make inputting a map really easy, but i got an error saying "NameError: name 'path' is not defined" as you can see, i've imported 'path' from os, so it should work but it doesn't!

heres the code in reference:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from os import path
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from tilemap import *
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(500, 100)
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        game_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
        self.map = Map(path.join(game_folder, 'map.txt'))

    def new(self):
        # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
            for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
                if tile == '1':
                    Wall(self, col, row)
                if tile == 'P':
                    self.player = Player(self, col, row)

    def run(self):
        # game loop - set self.playing = False to end the game
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        # update portion of the game loop
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        self.draw_grid()
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()

    def events(self):
        # catch all events here
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass

# create the game object
g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
    g.show_go_screen()
```

(by the way this is python code)

Comment: Is this all your code? If so, then path isn't imported or defined anywhere before you use it.

Comment: add `from os import path` to the top of your script

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't imported the path module from the os library correctly.

*path* is a module name, but you haven't imported it so the python interpreter doesn't know what this unknown variable is.

```
from os import path
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! however, i have put that in my code and it continues to not function. I also updated my code so what i have put in there can be seen.

Comment: @EZoCubeik In that case, if you are having errors with the exact code that you provided, my bets would be on a faulty IDE. Because I copied your code and chucked it into VS code and I did not get any errors regarding `path`. Try replacing `path` with `os.path`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Skkkitzo! i really appreciate it. However, it said that 'os' was not defined. Do you have an alternative fix?